# Citations to Mathematical Reviews?

Tags: review-databases

I have written a few reviews for Mathematical Reviews. But how do I cite such reviews in a bibliography?

This seems to be an open problem as I in a database written by others encountered a reference to a review I wrote which "cheated", as it were, and simply indicated Mathematical Reviews, Year, No. 1, pages 1-2.

Comment: You can cite it as a @misc entry in your .bib file

Comment: This was useful. You may write it as an answer.

Comment: Sure, you can now accept it as your answer. :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can cite it as a @misc entry in your .bib file.